# Get selected value from bootstrap country picker

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap country picker in my web form. I want to get the selected value from country picker.

Here's my country picker code:

```
<div id="country" class="form-group bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
        <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I try to get the selected value with this code (I'm using the post method to pass values):

```
Country.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["country"]);
```

I use another page (Country picker in Login.aspx, Data retrieving from another page Test.aspx) to retrieve the data.

But this is not giving me any result - what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit long winded but you could use jQuery to get the selected value and then pass that to an asp control...

```
//Get selected value
var selected = $( "#country option:selected" ).text();
//Then pass to control
var controlCountry = $("#<%=controlId.ClientID%>");
controlCountry.val = selected;
```

Hope it helps or puts you on the right path.